# scanning values using pointers by passing memory address

Tags: c, pointers

I am a student just started to learn programming using C.
I am now learning pointers and I am trying to scan the value in function using pointers.But I keep getting error. I do not know why.Thanks for your answers.

```
void inputValue(int *numptr);
int main()
{
    int input;
    inputValue(&input);
    printf("%d\n", input);
    return 0;
}
void inputValue(int *inputptr)
{
    printf("Enter the value");
    scanf_s("%d", *inputptr);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps because you're passing an `int` into `scanf_s()`. Try passing in `inputptr` instead of `*inputptr`.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: it is a memory error. I can build the code. But my prompt just keep auto closing.

Comment: Pump up the compiler's warning level, read the warnings issued by the compiler during compilation, understand them, fix the mistakes in your code the warning are pointing you to.

Comment: `scanf_s("%d", inputptr);`, You have to pass the pointer and not the value of the memory it points to. Which BTW is undetermined.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi: Hmhm, "*pass the pointer and not it's value*" what's the difference?

Comment: @alk is that better?

Comment: `scanf_s("%d", inputptr);`, You have to pass the pointer and not the value of the memory it points to. Which BTW is indetermined.

Comment: Aren't you getting any warning on this statement - `scanf_s("%d", *inputptr);`? Since you just started learning C programming, so a suggestion - don't ignore compiler warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solution for you, your function is wrong.
Function `scanf()` needs address of variable not value of variable.

Your code:

```
void inputValue(int *numptr);
int main()
{
    int input;
    inputValue(&input);
    printf("%d\n", input);
    return 0;
}
void inputValue(int *inputptr)
{
    printf("Enter the value");
    scanf_s("%d", *inputptr); // this is the problem
}
```

You have to pass into `scanf()` address of variable.

So, your function should be:

```
void inputValue(int * inputPtr)
{
    printf("ENTER:");
    scanf("%d", inputPtr);
}
```

If you have integer variable and you want to read to it:

```
int n;
scanf("%d", &n); //you have to pass address of n
```

But if you have pointer to variable:

```
int n;
int * ptr = &n;
scanf("%d", ptr); //address of n -> it is pointing to n
```

But if you write *ptr it means value of variable it's pointing to:

```
int n;
int * ptr = &n;
scanf("%d", *ptr); //value of n - wrong
```

It is not passing address of variable but its value.
So this is same:

```
int n;
scanf("%d", n); //value of n - wrong
```

Simple explanation pointers:

```
int n;
int * ptr = &n;

&n -> address of n
n -> value of n
ptr -> address of n 
*ptr -> value of n
&ptr -> address of pointer
```

And when we have function working with pointers:

```
void setval(int*, int);

void main(void)
{
     int n=54;
     setval(&n, 5); // passing address of n
     // now n=5
}

void setval(int * mem, int val)
{
     * mem = val; // it sets value at address mem to val
     // so it sets value of n to 5
     // if we passed only n not &n
     // it would mean address of value in n - if n would be 5 it's like we 
     // passed address in memory at 0x5
}
```